# how would I create a square that scroll's when its filled to the bottom with messages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a square that scrolls (automatically or by the user) when the created text nodes / msgs reach the bottom, and if they continue they disappear and are shown when the user scrolls down like a chat system, I have ran into many problems with trying to make the messages scroll. I have tried to make them inside of the square basically the square is the html page for the msg , but that hasn't work neither has trying to replicate the square by putting it in the same place and setting it to relative
with the property `overflow-y: auto;` <-- did nothin, relatived did  nothing either cause there is property's that need `fixed`, I have tried using google to search my problem and I found post using a way more complicated system that wouldn't / couldn't be changed so I tried w3wschool and dev mozz and surprisingly I didn't find anything just how to hide scrolling  using `overflow: hidden;` but I did find `overflow-y: auto;` could help on a webpage and have tried but have not succeeded. : **basically** : I need my sqar to scroll and messages to hide when they pass the bottom of the square and if the user catches up with the messages they show. they are never `display: none` just not there because you have to scroll down.

```js
var hi = 0;
var uses = 0;


function sent() {
  if (uses >= 0) {
    filter();
  } {
    uses++;
  }
}



function filter() {
  const Text = document.getElementById("tach").value;
  const tach = document.getElementById("tach");

  if (Text == '') {
    tach.style.animation = "wrong 1s linear"
    tach.value = "Must Contain a letter";
    tach.readOnly = true;
    tach.addEventListener("animationend", Re);
  } else if (Text.length == 1) {
    tach.style.animation = "wrong 1s linear"
    tach.value = "Must Have more than 1";
    tach.readOnly = true;
    tach.addEventListener("animationend", Re);
  } else if (Text == "hi") {
    const newDiv = document.createElement("message");

    const Text = document.getElementById("tach").value;

    const newContent = document.createTextNode("You:" + Text);

    const currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");

    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);

    //

    if (hi == 0) {

      sleep(2000).then(() => {
        const Div = document.createElement("reply");
        const txt = "Unkown:Hello";

        const Content = document.createTextNode(txt);


        Div.appendChild(Content);


        const currDiv = document.getElementById("div2");
        document.body.insertBefore(Div, currDiv);
        hi++;
      });
    } else if (hi == 1) {
      sleep(2000).then(() => {
        const Div = document.createElement("reply");
        const txt = "Unkown:Stop saying hello";

        const Content = document.createTextNode(txt);


        Div.appendChild(Content);


        const currDiv = document.getElementById("div2");
        document.body.insertBefore(Div, currDiv);
        hi++;
      });
    } else if (hi == 2) {

      sleep(2000).then(() => {
        const Div = document.createElement("reply");
        const txt = "Unkown:STOP saying hello";

        const Content = document.createTextNode(txt);


        Div.appendChild(Content);


        const currDiv = document.getElementById("div2");
        document.body.insertBefore(Div, currDiv);
        hi = 1;
      });
    }

  } else if (Text.match(/[a-z]/i)) {

    const newDiv = document.createElement("message");
    const Text = document.getElementById("tach").value;

    const newContent = document.createTextNode("You:" + Text);


    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);


    const currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);

  } else {
    tach.style.animation = "wrong 1s linear"
    tach.value = "Can't Contain a number";
    tach.readOnly = true;
    tach.addEventListener("animationend", Re);
  }

}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#for {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0.25rem;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  display: flex;
  height: 3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: normal;
}

#for>button {
  background: #333;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* User - Id - for  */


/* Input  -Value- */

#tach {
  border: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  cursor: text;
}

#tach:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* Input  */


/* Square */

#sqar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 250px;
  background: #505050;
  border: 4px solid #27282c;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #27282c;
  bottom: 5.886%;
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  cursor: normal;
}


/* */

message {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 436px;
  top: 510px;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.50;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
}

reply {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 436px;
  top: 510px;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(172, 172, 172);
  opacity: 0.50;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes wrong {
  0% {
    color: white;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
  }
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Game</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <user id="for">
    <input class="rab" id="tach" autocomplete="off"><button id="user" onclick="sent()">Send</button>
    <usermessage id="mesg"></usermessage>
    <sqr id="sqar"></sqr>

</body>

</html>
```

**Open snippet on full page**

Comment: I am not quite clear on the requirement. When the user adds another message do you want the existing messages to automatically scroll up so the new message is at the bottom of the square so it is visible?

Comment: yes but also can scroll up so the user can view previous messages